# Visual studio Ignore the .gitignore file

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I add to my project root the .gitignore file but I don't know why I still get the bin and debug folder
here is my .gitignore file

https://github.com/geshtop/5780_final1/blob/master/.gitignore

in the ignore file I have

```
*/bin/
```

and still files in bin folder shown

[image]

Comment: Are the files already tracked? As in, they are part of the previous revision? Then `.gitignore` won't work.

Comment: Yes the tracked but i want to remove them and ignore them from now